# How can I apply Storage methods to a JS object?

Tags: javascript, json, prototype, web-storage

I would like to be able to call the same methods of Storage { } to JS Objects { }.
These are particulary : `element.key(index)` and `element.length`.

I first though maybe we could do something as simple as `var NoBrowserBasedStorage = localStorage;` but it seems that it won't work, and localStorage will be used in parallel. The idea is to have a custom Object that is not at all based on the Browser, but still work as fast, as well and as if it was a localStorage.

Additional sub question, which is faster? `Object {}` or `Storage {}`?

Comment: If your running this on a browser the only place anything *can* be stored is the browser. Unless you are running something like node.js and want to store something on the server or a file.

Comment: I mean JS Object keeped in memory but not in browser data (such as localStorage).
But the goal is to have the same methods as Storage